# Jenkins parallel and sequential stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to run a job with parallel and sequential stages. My code looks like this, each stage will be a groovy script therefore I am running with parallel name: and not parallel {}

```
stage('Start profiling') {
steps {
    script{
        parallel stageParallel: {
            stage("parallel"){
                echo"parallel"
            }
        }, runTest: {
            stage("sequential 1"){
                echo "sequential 1 "
            }
            stage("sequential 2"){
                echo "sequential 2 "
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

[Image of Blue Ocean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJSBP.png)

As you can see it gets executed, but can´t see it on Open Blue Ocean as a step.

[Image of stage view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5TIV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying sequential stages within parallel stages tends to be flaky in Blue Ocean. There is an [open bug](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-55427?focusedCommentId=357611&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel) relating to your problem in the Jenkins bug backlog, but it hasn't been looked into since 2019. Unfortunately there is little you can do from your end since you pipeline code is obviously correct.